# Adding images to leafs of dendrogram, instead of text in R

Tags: r, image, label, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I'm trying to achieve a radial dendrogram, similar to the one below in R (see [this post](http://gastonsanchez.com/blog/how-to/2012/10/03/Dendrograms.html)). However, instead of the text on the leafs, I'd like to have an image, for example: [image]

Any idea how I could go about this?

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be an image or could you also use colored unicode symbols like ?

Comment: An image. If it were just unicode symbols, I would have used that as the text labels. Could maybe the `raster` package to draw the images on the plot at the label positions, but I'd need a way to get the x/y position of the labels and the rotation angle.

Answer (score 0):

While difficult with the circle dendrogram you show, you can do this with a vertical dendrogram with

```
grid::grid.raster(mypng, x=.9, y=.7, width=.5) 
rasterImage(as.raster(object), 5, 5, 6, 6)
```

Example

```
library(dendextend)
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(USArrests[1:5,])))
image <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol = 5, nrow = 3))
par(mar=c(10,3,3,0))
plot(dend)
rasterImage(as.raster(image), 1-0.5, -200, 1+0.5, -100, xpd=TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you explain, what this code do, and how it draws images on dendrogram leafs?